# Can't save big arrays into IndexedDB using db.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, windows-8, indexeddb, db.js

I tried to save a big array into a IndexedDB database using db.js. The Array contains, varying from the user, 100-1000 elements because I'm working at a Windows 8 Store-App in JS and the array contains objects for all photos found in the users picture library. I want to save that array into the database because I do not want to build it every time again. I get a DataCloneError while trying to save.

Here my code:

```
server.objects.add({
   id: 0,
   pic: nametowrite,
   value: contenttowrite
});

picturesLibrary.getItemsAsync().then(function (items) { 
    if (items.size == 0) { return }; 
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < items.size; i2++) { 
        if (items[i2].isOfType(Windows.Storage.StorageItemTypes.file)) { 
            if (filetype(items[i2].name) == true) { 
                pictures.push(items[i2]); 
            } 
        } else { 
            folders.push(items[i2]) 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Can you save small arrays? What makes you think that error is related to size?

Comment: Arrays in any size are savable if they not contain that image object

Answer (score 0):

That error is thrown if you try to save a DOM node, not from an array being too large. From [The Structured Clone Algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm) on MDN:

> - Attempting to clone DOM nodes will likewise throw a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception.

`contenttowrite` (assuming that's your image) will need to be a `blob`.

Here's an image to `blob` snippet:

```js
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    blob;
ajax.open( 'GET', 'example.png', true );
ajax.responseType = 'blob'; //the magic
ajax.addEventListener( 'load', function () {
    if ( ajax.status == 200 ) {
        blob = ajax.response;
    };
} );
ajax.send();
```

Comment: That has not worked. But the object is not taken from the DOM either. In Windows 8 WinJS Apps, there is a special object for files pulled from the users hard drive. So I have file objects instead of DOM nodes. How do I make them into blobs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Martin What is the data type of the object? Do a `console.log( typeof contenttowrite )`. Also, if you could post some code of how you're creating this object it would help.

Comment: `picturesLibrary.getItemsAsync().then(function (items) {
            if (items.size == 0) {return };
                for (var i2 = 0; i2 < items.size; i2++) {
                    if (items[i2].isOfType(Windows.Storage.StorageItemTypes.file)) {
                        if (filetype(items[i2].name) == true) {
                            pictures.push(items[i2]);
                        }
                    }
                    else { folders.push(items[i2]) }
                }
            });` Gets me the object. The array pictures will be contenttowrite

Comment: testing the array and a element contained in the array both gets me `object`. Testing one contained element with the Windows isOfType method gets me `Windows.Storage.StorageItemTypes.file`